# Come migliorare lo scritto in italiano?

Tags: writing

Come scrivere meglio in italiano? Avete  consigli? Io studio l'italiano. Lo capisco, ma non scrivo perfettamente.

Answer (score 4):

La cosa più semplice che puoi fare è leggere molto, scegliendo testi di generi diversi: dagli articoli di giornale ai romanzi.
In questo caso, prediligi opere moderne e contemporanee ai classici della letteratura: testi troppo vecchi potrebbero usare vocaboli, grafie e costruzioni sintattiche che oggi non si usano più o si usano pochissimo, quindi sono meno utili nell'ottica di migliorare il tuo italiano scritto di uso quotidiano.
Meglio ancora se quel che leggi è passato attraverso un processo di editing e correzione che abbia eliminato/ridotto al minimo gli errori di scrittura.

A seconda di quanto bene comprendi l'italiano, potresti decidere di iniziare rileggendo in italiano opere che hai già letto nella tua lingua, così da avere un'idea generale di ciò di cui si sta parlando, oppure di leggere opere per te completamente nuove.

Al di là della lettura, una buona grammatica ed un buon vocabolario sono ovviamente (quasi) essenziali quindi, se non li hai già, procurateli il prima possibile.

Answer (score 1):

Sono completamente d'accordo con quanto detto da @secan nella sua risposta: leggere è assolutamente necessario per acquistare la padronanza della scrittura. Ma, secondo la mia esperienza, è altrettanto importante procurarsi delle occasioni per scrivere testi in italiano con certa assiduità.

Puoi cominciare con piccoli testi e, poco a poco, provare a farli più lunghi. Cerca alcuni italiani che siano disposti a correggere gli errori nei tuoi testi: esistono parecchi siti web che funzionano come reti sociali con la finalità di imparare le lingue in cui puoi fare questo tipo di esercizi. Procura di capire le ragioni di tali errori e chiedi (per esempio, su Italian.SE) su tutto quello che non riesci veramente a comprendere.